# How to change Apache server to IIS server and MS SQL server database?

Tags: domains, server, ftp

I have a domain with Apache server. I have the FTP logins. I want to change it to IIS server and MS SQL server database. How to convert it and who will do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Domain does not come with attached Apache server as you think.

Domain name has [Name Servers](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_server&ei=llreUpuZKomOrQei7IHgCw&usg=AFQjCNF1BNrtMsdadIZd9hL97_ck1hSsvA&sig2=rglxTMdGSIaBnrchDXeCkw&bvm=bv.59568121,d.bmk) which actually point to the location of your server.

**To change the domain name from one hosting to another, simply change the nameserver of the domain to the new hosting.**

This either you can do it on your own from Domain Control Panel or get the customer-support to do it for you. DNS change can take around 24 hours to take effect. You just buy an IIS hosting with MS-SQL database. If you can change your hosting plan with current service provider, then this might be even more easy.

Simplified Words :

1. Find Out Name Servers for Your Hosting Account.
2. Replace nameserver of domain to the nameserver of new hosting(IIS server in your case)
3. Wait for the DNS change to propagate.

Cheers